# Receiving Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 during VUGen script replay

Tags: oracle, loadrunner

I am currently testing HP LoadRunner 12.50 with Oracle EBS R12.2.5. I created a simple script for web and Oracle EBS application using protocols (Oracle NCA + Web – Http/HTML) for scenario (Log in to web, bring up a Oracle form, save the oracle form, close the form and log out) and replayed, but ran into below error.

Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error)

I am unable to resolve the above error, though performed correlations for the script but still the error occurred. I am not familiar with developing VUGen script for Oracle forms using HP LoadRunner. In the Runtime Settings > Browser > Browser Emulation > Use Browser > Browser Version = 11.0 & Internet Protocol > Preferences > HTTP > ‘Keep-Alive HTTP connections’ is checked.

How can I replay the script without getting the error? Are there any new correlations to be added manually and what are the new correlation, if any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is a combination of process and  tool mechanics.    On the process front, you need to be explicitly checking for expected results.  What happens most commonly in a 500 situation is that you have a failure to check for  positive, expected results, taking an HTTP 200 as a positive result and then moving to the next step.  However, you can get a 500 with inappropriate content for positive execution of the business process.  You then move to the next step and "Whammo!" Here comes an HTTP 500 for an out of context request.

In your code

1. Explicitly check for positive expected results in content.  See web_reg_*() functions for context on this.  This is also covered in training and the available tutorials
2. When you do not find your positive, expected result, then branch your code and exit the iteration